# How to save form data to my model in django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a newsletter application that requires the user's name and email. However each time I input form data . no change is reflected in the database

**models.py**

```
class NewUsers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "NewUser"
        verbose_name_plural = "NewUsers"

    def __str__(seld):
         return self.email
```

**views.py**

```
def newsletter_subscribe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name'] #variable to store cleaned data
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            instance = NewUsers(name= name, email = email)
            instance.save()
            if NewUsers.objects.filter(email = instance.email).exists():
                print("Your email is already added to our database")
            else:
                instance.save()
                print("Thank you for subscribing")

     else:
        form = NewUserForm()#display empty form
        context = {'form':form}
        template = "index.html"
        return render(request ,template ,context )
```

Here is my template code

> template

```
 <form  method="post" action="{%url 'subscribe'%}">
  {% csrf_token %}
 <label for="id_email_field">Name:</label> <input type="text" 
  name=""
 required="" id="">
<label for="id_email_field">E-mail:</label> <input type="email" 
name="email_field"
 required="" id="id_email_field">
<button id="id_submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe" 
 type="submit">Subscribe
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The only reason seems to be that `form.is_valid()` is not true... (ps: please indent your last else properly)

Comment: How to properly use ModelForms is fully documented: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 1):

A few things I notice: First, a view must return an HttpResponse object. E.g., I recommend reading up here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/ and here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/
So, since apparently you didnt get an error thrown at you pointing to this fact, I assume that the request.method never has been equal "POST". Maybe you could try to find out if this is the case? Therefore: could you also provide your template code, please.

Next, your code in the if form.is_valid() is quite contrived. The most natural thing to do here is just calling form.save(). This will create an instance in your db out of the cleaned form-data. In case, you need to do some adjustments, you can extend like this:

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
# add some adjustments (instance.foo = bar)
instance.save()
```

Last, as noted before, you need to return an HttpResponse object which is usually done via

```
return redirect(url_name, ..)
```

Edit: since you now added the template code: Try to first let django render the fields for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually
and then have a look at the source code of the template. Your name-input-field is missing a name tag and your email-input-field should have name="email" I think. You can django even let the whole form render for you (see docs again...) Without (correct) name tags in the input fields - it will not be possible to send or correctly assign the data inputted by the user.

Comment: The OP didn't post the form's code so you can't assume he's using a ModelForm.

Comment: I am using ModelForm